# Weird Entitlements issue on Distribution

Tags: ios, xamarin, code-signing-entitlements

I'm having a strange issue when I attempt to sign an iOS app for distribution. (The app happens to be a Xamarin.Forms app but I'm not sure thats relevant).

I build and archive for publishing just fine, but when I sign the app I get the following error:

Publishing failed
“The iCloud entitlement ‘com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment’ is not supported by the Provisioning Profile.

The odd thing is that my Entitlements for this app are empty. I don’t specify iCloud as an entitlement and I've double checked the App ID in the Apple developer portal and that has only Game Center and In-App Purchases enabled.

When I use the codesign tool (ala codesign -d --entitlements :- "Payload/MyApp.app") I can see that cloud kit is certainly in there.

Where oh where is this cloud kit entitlement being specified?!

Comment: Have a 3rd-party library in your app that is including iCloud?

Comment: That wasn't it.  I cleanup up my local profiles and rebuilt and things went back to normal.